# ReadList and ToExpression

Tags: import

My dataset is like:

> id,   feat_1, feat_2, feat_8, feat_9, feat_10,    feat_11,    feat_17,    feat_18,    feat_22,    feat_2, target
>
> 1,    1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  2,  0,  1,  0,  Class_1
>   2,    0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  2,  0,  0,  Class_1

The file is very large, so I don't want to use 'Import". Therefore I would like to use 'ReadList'

```
strm = OpenRead["test.TXT"];
Skip[strm, String, 1];
dataM = ToExpression@
  ReadList[strm, Table[Record, {12}], NullRecords -> True, 
   RecordSeparators -> {",", "\n"}]
Close[strm];
```

The output is: 
{1, 1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  2,  0,  1,  0, Class_}

The integer in 'Class_1" disapeared. If I don't use 'ToExpression@' then all integers are seen as strings ("1", "1"....)

Anyone a suggestion how to solve this issue

Comment: The underscore `_` as a pattern matching mechanism is reserved for mathematica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underscore `_` as a pattern matching mechanism is [reserved](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html) for mathematica. Therefore, either use something like

```
dataM = ReadList[strm, Table[Record, {12}], NullRecords -> True, 
RecordSeparators -> {",", "\n"}];

output = Table[Flatten[{ToExpression[Drop[dataM[[i]], -1]], Last[dataM[[i]]]}],
{i,1,Length[dataM]}];
```

or remove the underscore in your data file.